# Suppress "Chrome for Testing" infobar with selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

When launching the Chrome WebDriver, two bars appear indicating the use of an automated testing version. By using the <options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["--enable-automation"])> option, one of the two bars has disappeared. Do you know how to remove the other one?

I have tried passing it other options without success. I expect, through an option, to be able to suppress the bar that prompts for the download of the standard version of Chrome.[Download standard version infobar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TdEW.png)

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look at the code, this bar seems to be fixed. One way to overcome the problem is to use different binaries.

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium"

or

options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium-browser"